AWS Athena - mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'MATERIALIZED', 'MULTI', 'OR', 'PROTECTED', 'ROLE', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'
I'm getting this error when I try to create a table in Athena. Below is the create table query. I'm not sure what is the syntax error. Could someone help?
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exportedfroms3.timtams (
  Item struct < tams_id: struct < s: string >,
  last_updated: struct < s: string >,
  id: struct < s: string >,
  rig: struct < m: struct < summary: struct < s: string >,
                            future_programme: struct < s: string >,
                            technologies: struct < l: array < struct < s: string > > >,
                            owner: struct < s: string >,
                            lead_programme: struct < s: string >,
                            level: struct < s: string >,
                            domain: struct < s: string >,
                            location: struct < s: string >,
                            attributes: struct < m: struct < execution_type: struct < s.string >,
                                                             gitlab_runner: struct < bool: string >,
                                                             schedulable: struct < bool: string >,
                                                             is_safe: struct < bool: string > > >,
                            primary_contact: struct < s: string >,
                            status: struct < s: string >,
                            commissioned: struct < s: string > > >,
  type: struct < s: string > >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'ignore.malformed.json' = 'FALSE',
  'dots.in.keys' = 'FALSE',
  'case.insensitive' = 'TRUE',
  'mapping' = 'TRUE'
)
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://dynamodb-athena-test/AWSDynamoDB/01727258263124-ea55e337/data/test/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification' = 'json');


There is definitely something off with execution_type: struct < s.string > - shouldn't it be s: string. But probably that's not the only problem. Can you provide example data?

Hi Philipp, Thank you very much. That was the only syntax error.
